# List out of range for gradient creator

Tags: python, gradient

I am working on a pygame-gradient creator, but i cant find the problem. It says that the list is out of range.

```
class Gradient:
    def Gradient(col1,col2,l,b):
        gradient = list()
        for i in range((l*b) + 1):
            gradient=[None] * i
        for i in range(l):
            gradient[l]=((col1[0]-(i*(col1[0]/l)))+(col2[0]-((l-i)*(col2[0]/l))), (col1[1]-(i*(col1[1]/l)))+(col2[1]-((l-i)*(col2[1]/l))), (col1[2]-(i*(col1[2]/l)))+(col2[2]-((l-i)*(col2[2]/l))))
        for i in range(b-1):
            for j in range(l):
                gradient[(b+1*j)+j] = gradient[i]
        return gradient
```

Comment: What is the exact error?

Comment: Please post the full error including the line where this error occurs.

Comment: Why are you using the same variable i twice in consecutive for loops

Comment: this is the error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    Gradient.Gradient((100,100,100),(0,0,0),20,1)
  File "/Users/Casper_Gamer/Desktop/Gradient.py", line 7, in Gradient
    gradient[l]=((col1[0]-(i*(col1[0]/l)))+(col2[0]-((l-i)*(col2[0]/l))), (col1[1]-(i*(col1[1]/l)))+(col2[1]-((l-i)*(col2[1]/l))), (col1[2]-(i*(col1[2]/l)))+(col2[2]-((l-i)*(col2[2]/l))))
IndexError: list assignment index out of range